# Find dictionary key using value from list

Tags: python, dictionary

i'm trying to find a element in a list and return the the key who has that list.
Example:

```
mydict = {'hi':[1,2], 'hello':[3,4]}

print(find(1))
return 'hi
```

Is there any simple way to do it?

Comment: You will have to first iterate over all the values then over each list, so `O(n * m)` where `n` is the number of keys and `m` is the longest list. **However**, if you manage a second dict where the key is a value from the first dict and the value is a list of keys from the first dict, then you can solve this in `O(1)`

Comment: Another compromise will be to turn the lists to sets (if the items are hashable), then you will be able to get it done with `O(n)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply loop through your dictionary as key,value pairs and your search value is in values list, it will return the value.

Code:

```py
mydict = {'hi':[1,2], 'hello':[3,4]}

def find(item):
    for key, value in mydict.items():
        if item in value:
            return key
        
print(find(1))
```

Output: `hi`

Answer (score 1):

This function will return all the keys that contain the given value as a list.

```
def find(to_find, inp_dct):
    return [i for i in inp_dct if to_find in inp_dct[i]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for k in mydict:
    if val in mydict[k]:
        print(k)
```

Where val is the value you want to find.

Comment: Can it be done with a list comprehension?

Comment: List comprehension returns a list, in the above example you requested to return the key, please try to be more specific so i can help.

Comment: `[k for k,v in mydict.items() if val in v]`, in that case you are getting a list with all the keys that val is a part of the list(v). Also, if you find my comments usefull you can upvote them :)